# How to customize tooltip styling in for Scatter plot in Highchart?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I need to customize the styling (background color, border, etc) of a tooltip for a high chart plot.

I know that I can set the tooltop like this:

```
scatter: {
  ...
  tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '...',
      pointFormat: '...',
  }
```

}
but I need more styling options like background color, etc.  For some reason it doesn't work when I try to set these properties like in a regular tooltip like this:

```
scatter: {
  ...
  tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '...',
      pointFormat: '...',
      backgroundColor: 'black',
  }

}
```

So how DO you make a customized tooltip with a scatter chart in highschart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define tooltip options on the main level:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '...',
        pointFormat: '...',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6gxcanhs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip

Comment: that did the trick